# i can't instanciate a class with no arguments using spring

Tags: spring, spring.net

I have a class with a constructor without arguments and I want to instantiate using spring, but I get the following error:

Error creating context 'spring.root': Cannot instantiate a class that does not have a no-argument constructor

Here the configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="spring">
      <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler, Spring.Core" />
      <section name="objects" type="Spring.Context.Support.DefaultSectionHandler, Spring.Core" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <spring>
    <context>
      <resource uri="config://spring/objects" />
    </context>
    <objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
      <object name="metier" type="Metier.ImpotMetier, Metier">

      </object>
    </objects>
  </spring>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Question: how can I instantiate this class and use its methods in another project?

Comment: Create a no-argument ctor?

Comment: I think spring is disagreeing with you - the class doesn't have a visible no-argument constructor

Comment: Did you create the `ImpotMetier`class,or is it in a library you referenced? If the class is yours, please add it to the question. If it isn't, then the library creator might have good reasons not to have a argument-less constructor and you should use one of the other constructors.

Comment: yes 'impotMetier' class is defined in Metier library created by me and I would like to instantiate this class using spring. My problem is when I add a constructor with no parameters in impotMetier class i forgot to build it, thats why spring throw error

Comment: ah, glad you solved this. Consider answering your own question, so that everybody knows your problem was solved.